# Remove path from $PATH macOS Mojave

Tags: python, bash, path

I am trying to set up my new MacBook, and installed python 3.7, however realised that I would rather use python 3.6. I uninstalled python 3.7, however the python path is still in my $PATH alongside the path for python 3.6. The questions which I have seen on this topic seem to give answers which involve using `export PATH` which only changes the path for the current session, or say that the measure which needs to be taken depends on your system configuration and version of macOS

`echo $PATH` gives:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

I have already deleted the `../3.7` which is being pointed to, so would like to only have the `3.6` path in `$PATH`

Comment: **How** did you install Python? It’s probably better to install it via Homebrew or Conda in the future to avoid these problems.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, I just used the python download from python.org. ````python --version```` in terminal gives ````Python 3.6.9```` so I'm not sure I need to remove the path to 3.7 but I would rather it not be there as I have uninstalled it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to your home directory, `cd ~`.

Open `.bash_profile` file.
Like so,

`open .bash_profile`

Make changes to the path variable in the end of the file.

Save and exit.

Now close the current terminal and open new one. The changes will sustain.

Also for using `python` of your wish you can alias it in `.bash_profile` (obviously after setting `PATH` variable).

Like,

```
alias python="python3.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`, but write it in the .bash_profile or the .bashrc in your user.

That is, if you are using bash.

Maybe you will find already a definition of PATH in there, so you can just change it.